# Why there is no filterValues() method for ListMultiMaps in Guava?

Tags: java, guava, multimap

Actual problem I face is to filter the values of a `ListMultimap<K, V>` based on a arbitrary/flexible `Predicate<V>`.

```
Predicate<Integer> filterCondition = i -> i > 42;
ListMultimap<String, Integer> myMap = MultimapBuilder.hashKeys().arrayListValues().build();
// populate myMap ...

// below does not work 
myMap = Multimaps.filterValues(myMap, filterCondition);
```

The last line does not work becouse Guava has no `<K, V> ListMultimap<K, V> filterValues(ListMultimap<K, V> unfiltered, final Predicate<? super V> valuePredicate)` that would be useful here, even though it has both

- `public static <K,V> Multimap<K,V> filterValues(Multimap<K,V> unfiltered, Predicate<? super V> valuePredicate)` and
- `public static <K,V> SetMultimap<K,V> filterValues(SetMultimap<K,V> unfiltered, Predicate<? super V> valuePredicate)`.

Why was that omitted?

I ended up with the following workaround but this just seems unnecessarily complex (and possibly inefficient).

```
ListMultimap<String, Integer> myNewMap = MultimapBuilder.hashKeys().arrayListValues().build();
myMap.entries().stream().filter(e -> filterCondition.test(e.getValue()))
    .forEach(e -> myNewMap.put(e.getKey(), e.getValue()));
myMap = myNewMap;
```

Answer (score 1):

`myMap.get(index)` would take linear time to execute, but *typically* `List` implementations offer constant-time `get`. This is the same reason that [we don't offer `Lists.filter`](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/IdeaGraveyard#listsfilter).

Now it's true that that `get` executes in constant time only *typically*. Notably, [`LinkedList.get` takes linear time](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/util/LinkedList.html). But `LinkedList` itself is the wrong choice for most use cases, so we usually don't want to follow its precedent.

On top of all that, we somewhat regret *all* our lazily computed "view" collections -- *all* our collection filtering and transformation. So that's yet more reason not to offer more such APIs. [We recommend filtering or transforming eagerly, as the JDK does with its `Stream` API.](https://github.com/google/guava/issues/2348#issuecomment-849875560)